# How to solve the METRO in IARCS

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

The link to the problem is-http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/METRO
I have no clue as to how to go about this problem.

Comment: Post your question and attempt here, not just a link to a question somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a token at the starting station. When a train passes through the station, it "picks up" a copy of the token and then "drops off" copies of it at each stop.

Similarly, when any train passes through a station with a token, it picks up a copy if it doesn't have one already.

Simulate this until the destination station receives a token.

There are `N+M` trains to keep track of, and at most `O(N+M)` steps before the destination station receives a token. Hence this should run in `O((N+M)^2)` time.

You can simulate this implicitly by having a counter for each station and propagating a newly-updated counter's value along its row and column with arithmetic, but it's still going to be quadratic time because you've got a quadratic number of stations to deal with, so you may as well do it explicitly and keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks!it was tough coding it..!but done

Comment: If you're happy with the solution, mind marking it off as "accepted" so it disappears from the tag:algorithms queue? Even better, if you came up with a better solution, you should post that and then accept that instead :)